# get() the name of an uploaded file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a simple question regarding my snippet of code below.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  fileInput("x", "upload file", accept = c(
    "text/csv",
    "text/comma-seperated-values, text/plain",
    ".csv")),

  tableOutput("my_csv")
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  csv <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$x
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df<- read.csv2(inFile$datapath, header=T)
    return(df)
  })

  output$my_csv <- renderTable({
    validate(need(!is.null(csv()),'no file yet.'))
      csv()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I want is a function like get() to print the name of the uploaded csv-file.
In the next step I want to create a list (named "list") with the uploaded file as its first object with the file's name.
So, if the uploaded file's name is "squirrel.csv" and I call list$squirrel.csv I want to see the table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to extract `basename` from the `name` field in `input$x` (`x` because your `inputId` is called `x`).

Add this to server part:

```
output$my_csv_name <- renderText({
  # Test if file is selected
  if (!is.null(input$x$datapath)) {
      # Extract file name (additionally remove file extension using sub)
      return(sub(".csv$", "", basename(input$x$name)))
  } else {
      return(NULL)
  }
})
```

To ui part add following line to display file name:

```
textOutput("my_csv_name")
```